# Javascript for loop to use array of images as enemies

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, loops, for-loop

I have an html file where it sets an array of images parsed from an xml file.

```
var states = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("random_state");

for(var i=0; i<states.length;i++)
{
    var xx = states[i].getElementsByTagName("random_image");

    for(var j=0; j<xx.length;j++)
    {

        randomurl = xx[j].childNodes[j].nodeValue
        }
    }
```

and within my game.js file i have this

```
I.sprite  = Sprite(randomurl);
```

which sets the image of the enemy. randomurl is a global variable within the html file

My problem is that instead of showing the array of images on screen it only shows the very last image from the array. I have tried multiple ways to do this and each time i fail.
I'm trying to use the entire array of images to show as enemies.

xml code simply returns 4 images which is an array of images stored in a database. The code is too comprehensive to add. But i have tested that my images return correctly as i can get them to appear in a div. My problem is that they are to appear as enemies and so only the last image from the array is shown as a sprite although i need all the returned images to fill this sprite?

XML code

```
$obj2 = StatesCollection::GetRandomStateImages($_GET['state_abbreviation']);
foreach($obj2 as $row2)             
{
    $random_url="./images/" . $row2['state_image']; 
    $response .= '<random_state><random_image>' . htmlentities($random_url, ENT_QUOTES) . '</random_image></random_state>';
}
```

it returns images from method in a database.

and the function of game.js which holds enemies

```
 function Enemy(I) {
          I = I || {};

          I.active = true;
          I.age = Math.floor(Math.random() * 128);

          I.color = "#A2B";

          I.x = width / 4 + Math.random() * width / 2;
          I.y = 0;
          I.xVelocity = 0
          I.yVelocity = 2;

          I.width = 32;
          I.height = 32;

          I.inBounds = function() {
            return I.x >= 0 && I.x <= width &&
              I.y >= 0 && I.y <= height;
          };

            I.sprite  = Sprite(randomurl);

          I.draw = function() {
            this.sprite.draw(canvas, this.x, this.y);
          };

          I.update = function() {
            I.x += I.xVelocity;
            I.y += I.yVelocity;

            I.xVelocity = 3 * Math.sin(I.age * Math.PI / 64);

            I.age++;

            I.active = I.active && I.inBounds();
          };

          I.explode = function() {
            Sound.play("explosion");

            this.active = false;
            // Extra Credit: Add an explosion graphic
          };

          return I;
        };
```

the sprite class which controls the sprites

```
(function() {
  function LoaderProxy() {
    return {
      draw: $.noop,
      fill: $.noop,
      frame: $.noop,
      update: $.noop,
      width: null,
      height: null
    };
  }

  function Sprite(image, sourceX, sourceY, width, height) {
    sourceX = sourceX || 0;
    sourceY = sourceY || 0;
    width = width || image.width;
    height = height || image.height;

    return {
      draw: function(canvas, x, y) {
        canvas.drawImage(
          image,
          sourceX,
          sourceY,
          width,
          height,
          x,
          y,
          width,
          height
        );
      },

      fill: function(canvas, x, y, width, height, repeat) {
        repeat = repeat || "repeat";
        var pattern = canvas.createPattern(image, repeat);
        canvas.fillColor(pattern);
        canvas.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
      },

      width: width,
      height: height
    };
  };

  Sprite.load = function(url, loadedCallback) {
    var img = new Image();
    var proxy = LoaderProxy();

    img.onload = function() {
      var tile = Sprite(this);

      $.extend(proxy, tile);

      if(loadedCallback) {
        loadedCallback(proxy);
      }
    };

    img.src = url;

    return proxy;
  };

  window.Sprite = function(name, callback) {
    return Sprite.load(name, callback);
  };
  window.Sprite.EMPTY = LoaderProxy();
  window.Sprite.load = Sprite.load;
}());
```

Comment: Did you declare randomurl as a var anywhere? I don't see it in the code block above. Also, you need a semicolon after nodeValue...wait nevermind about declaring randomurl as var

Comment: obviously `randomurl` will be assigned the last value of your nodes, i.e. `xx[xx.length-1].childNodes[xx.length-1].nodeValue;`

Comment: well do you have any additional help as to what it should do? your comment is helpful to identify a problem but its not entirely an answer?

Comment: So you want one sprite to contain all four images? How does your `Sprite` class work? Is it from some library that you haven't mentioned?

Comment: Thank you, but you didn't answer my first question. Is it that you want one sprite to contain all four images? It looks like the `Sprite` constructor only allows for specifying one image. How should the images be arranged relative to each other?

Comment: @JLRishe sorry man yeah the enemy sprite should display the images returned by xml code. It simply shows the last image from the array. Although i want it to loop through and display all of the images returned by the xml code. I'm not sure what you mean by arranged?

Comment: So you're saying that you want it to animate them and rotate through them one at a time over and over, or show them all at the same time? That's what I meant by arranged.

Comment: @JLRishe  basically i have a number of enemies. The loop should simply loop through the given images and apply it to an enemy. i dont want it animating. just when the enemy is created give it one of the images from the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I think I finally understand that you want an array of URLs, and to go through them and use a different one each time you create an enemy. In order to do this, I recommend keeping a global array of urls instead of a single one. I'll call it `enemyUrls`.  You can populate it like this:

```
var states = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("random_state"), 
    imgUrlNode, i;
enemyUrls = [];

for(i = 0; i < states.length;i++) {
    imgUrlNode = states[i].getElementsByTagName("random_image")[0];

    if (imgUrlNode) {
        enemyUrls.push(imgUrlNode.nodeValue);
    }
}
```

Add one more global variable called `currentImg` and initialize it to 0:

```
var currentImg = 0;
```

Then when you create your enemy, do this:

```
I.sprite  = Sprite(enemyUrls[currentImg]);
currentImg = (currentImg + 1) % enemyUrls.length;
```

Comment: I have an array of images. I do not want a random image showing from this array. I want ALL the images to be displayed. So my problem is that it only displays the last of the array? There is no need for the xml to be shown as i have tested everything up until this point. The XML simply returns 4 images. These are the images that i want to display. I tried out your code and it works but it only shows one random image but i want all 4 images to be displayed

Comment: @Samir_K_92 In that case, you're going to need to show us more of your code. We have no idea how the images are added to your game beside that single line you gave us. The code you have now will just overwrite `randomUrl` until it gets to the last one, and that's the value it will have when the loop ends. And please provide us your XML whether you think it is necessary or not.

Comment: okay that's me edited my question for you. thanks for your time

Comment: OMG IM GONNA COME OVER AND KISS YOU! Man I've been stuck for days!! i had to do some editing of your code but i got it! you're the man!!